# Gtk open default file manager folder

Tags: c, gtk2

I am in need to open the default file manager of the user's system (not a dialog, but the file manager used by the system) using gtk and C.

meaning, when a user chooses a directory, file manager will open and not a dialog. is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should launch [xdg-open](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open), e.g. with ordinary fork & exec.

E.g. this will open default file manager at `/`:

```
if(fork() == 0) {
    system("xdg-open /");
}
```

Comment: Wanted to clearify this, if I do

system("xdg-open ~/Music");

It will open for me 2 directories. directory "/" and directory "Music". Is there any way to get past it, So I will open only "Music" folder?

Comment: Weird. Does it happen if you launch this command from terminal? Is that the only change in code you've made?

Comment: nope not from the command line, only when called from the code it will open the root directory also

Comment: It happens on debian also, opens root directory and directory specified

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you provide minimal verifiable example either by editing your question or by asking separate one?

Answer (score 7):

You should use GIO:

```
GError *error = NULL;
if (!g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri ("file:///", NULL, &error)) {
    g_warning ("Failed to open uri: %s", error->message);
}
```

Note that this almost certainly requires a running GLib main loop (but if you're using GTK+, you already have that).

Also, there's no 100% guarantee that a file manager will be opened, but on any sanely set up system that is going to be the default handler for uris that are directories.

On a normal GNOME system @keltars xdg-open method forks, runs a shell script that starts a binary that then runs the same `g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the useful and important add!